# Embedded Google map not showing when using more than one Google account

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I've embedded a Google map that I created using Google account A.

- **If I am not logged in** to any Google account and visit the website then the map works fine.
- **If I log in to one Google account** (let's say Google account B) and visit the site then the map works fine.
- **If I 'Add another account'** or sign in to another Google account (let's say account C) in the same browser then I get a little red monster icon instead of the map and the message "www.google.com redirected you too many times".
- **If I sign out of all Google accounts** then the map works fine.
- Again, if I sign in with one account then the map appears correctly.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it? I'm finding that quite a few people are running two Google accounts.

There's no message in the console. We use Drupal but I've embedded the map in a simple HTML page and the result is the same as above, so I guess it's a Google issue. I couldn't find anything online about it, except a comment in a Scandinavian forum that maps don't show if you are logged in with more than one account.

It's also not a problem with the maps' sharing permissions. They are all public.

**Update**:
I've narrowed the problem down a bit. This isn't an issue on our web server because, as I mentioned, I can replicate it in a static HTML page opened from my desktop in a browser, with no server, CMS or .htaccess file involved. Instead it appears to be an issue related to my institutional Google account. I have two personal accounts and an institutional one.

- If I log in with my institutional account first then sign in with
  another account the maps don't work.
- If I sign in with a personal account then sign in with my institutional account the maps work.
- If I sign in with any combination of the personal accounts then the maps
  work.

So the problem occurs when I'm signed in with the Google account provided by my institution, then I sign in with another Google account. It doesn't matter which account created the map.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does anyone know why this was downvoted? Google suggest coming to SO for support on maps embed issues: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/support
That's why I posted here rather than Google maps forums.

Comment: The error "www.google.com redirected you too many times" is not a google maps embed api issue. The error “too many redirects” means that the website keeps being redirected between different addresses in a way that will never complete. This was discussed in this link: (https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-too-many-redirects/)

Comment: @Pagemag Thanks for that link - very useful! It's not our website, though, because the same happens on a local static HTML file. See my update. So I'm guessing it's a Google account issue that affects Google maps. I'm still investigating...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the answer: the administrators of the institutional GSuite account had not enabled Google Maps for our accounts.

According to [this thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/how-do-i-change-my-default-account-with-google-multiple-sign-in)  the first Google account you log in to is treated as your default account. So when I logged in to my institutional Google account then logged in to another account my permissions were inherited from my institutional Google account.

That doesn't explain why I can see the maps when I am *only* logged in to my institution account, but it seems from comments online (like in the thread I linked to) that accessing services through multiple accounts can be buggy.

So the error message given by the browsers wasn't helpful in this case. The root cause wasn't to do with redirects but account permissions to view maps.